# Number of arrangements that contain at least 1 path from top to bottom of 2D matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra, graph-theory

I have a $n\times n$ matrix of objects. $n'$ objects are black, and the rest $n^2-n'$ are white.

With that information, I can easily calculate the total number of black element arrangements that exist in the 2D matrix by using basic combinatorics: $C(n^2, n')$

Given the number of black elements present in the matrix, I aim to calculate the number of possible arrangements of those $ n'$ elements that contain at least one path from top to bottom of the grid (or vice-versa). However, I didn't find any direct formula or expression that relates $n^2$ and $n'$ to get that number.

How can I approach this problem without making an estimation or a simulation to obtain the number?

Edit: Consider a path from top to bottom in the matrix as a sequence of colored elements with the first one positioned in the first row of the grid and the last one in the corresponding opposite (last) row. For every contiguous pair of elements in the sequence, their distance must be 0; that is, they must be neighbors horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, and there is no limit or restriction for a path's length.

Also, I found an expression when the path length equals the side length of the matrix:
$(n + 2) \cdot 3^{(n-2)} + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-3} M_{k} \cdot (n-k-2) \cdot 3^{(n-k-3)}
$ with $M_{k}$ being the $k$ Motzkin number, but still looking for a general expression for any number of elements.

Comment: This seems closely related to the theory of percolation.

Comment: What does your last paragraph mean? What should we "note"? - the definition in the previous paragraph doesn't seem to mention anything at all special about the first or last columns.

Comment: (More generally, I would guess that it's too optimistic to "approach this problem without making an estimation or a simulation to obtain the number". Unless there is some very nice special structure hidden in the problem -- e.g. like you might occasionally get for certain percolation problems on 'self-dual' graphs -- there doesn't seem to any reason to expect a simple "direct formula or expression".)

Comment: @james-martin The last paragraph means you don't need to account for paths from left-right sides of the matrix. Only top-bottom ones, although you can rotate the matrix and it would be invariant. Also, my goal is to achieve an expression for the number of arrangements with at least one path given the size $n\times n$ of the matrix and $n'$ elements in it, or the opposite proposition, since it seems a bit easy to calculate.

Comment: @sam-hopkins Yes, this question arose from a percolation detection algorithm, more specifically with its time complexity analysis.

Comment: @Cardstdani ok, I see - then it would be much clearer without that last paragraph. It's already clear that you are asking about paths between the top and bottom. And those paths _are_ allowed to have starting or ending points in the first and last columns.

Comment: @james-martin Thanks, do you have any clue about any combinatorial structure that could adequately fit the problem?

Comment: @Cardstdani I don't - as I said, it seems too optimistic to hope for an "exact solution"! Of course, you can look for bounds or asymptotics.

Comment: Just checking -- do you allow the path to turn upwards at some points? Asking because if you do not allow that, i.e. if a path must proceed monotonously from top to bottom, the problem would likely be easier, and admit some kind of dynamic programming solution (proceed row by row). Also, such monotonous paths would give a lower bound for the general case.

Comment: @jukka-kohonen Yes, the path can change direction as often as possible inside the matrix. If the path were monotonous, the problem would be much easier. But unfortunately, a path has no such restrictions.