# Generalization of polynomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm dealing with a hard combinatorial problem where for every positive integer value of a variable $n$ I have to calculate a list of numbers, specifically $n^2$, that depend on $n$ and its list index value $k$. If you want to know more about the specific problem, you can visit [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461340/number-of-arrangements-that-contain-at-least-1-path-from-top-to-bottom-of-2d-mat).

In order to find an expression that relates each list number to its corresponding index and $n$ parameter, I have interpolated the values of the lists with a small $n$ and it results in the following polynomials:

$n=2\\ \frac{1}{24} \left(9 x^4-86 x^3+243 x^2-166 x\right)$

$n=3 \\ \frac{502 x^9-18945 x^8+291552 x^7-2350026 x^6+10651494 x^5-27496665 x^4+40248308 x^3-31279644 x^2+9953424 x}{362880}$

$n=4\\ \frac{177541 x^{16}-22889912 x^{15}+1342669060 x^{14}-47417636000 x^{13}+1124531200702 x^{12}-18915280062224 x^{11}+232422190140140 x^{10}-2117978597020000 x^9+14389512273652373 x^8-72689238663057016 x^7+270052102151435240 x^6-722263115740129600 x^5+1340234906635554384 x^4-1618739915026750848 x^3+1127409710876962560 x^2-336490569254246400 x}{20922789888000}$

$n=5 \\\frac{-230218824 x^{25}+73266563875 x^{24}-11011110755100 x^{23}+1039173229994050 x^{22}-69080938164907680 x^{21}+3439419373674609325 x^{20}-133132204898001530100 x^{19}+4105134296351411573800 x^{18}-102505912314431497670040 x^{17}+2095919942184623633667325 x^{16}-35348224418771136389804100 x^{15}+493855634113556120475623050 x^{14}-5726224068277869336725620560 x^{13}+55080845465490791263039627075 x^{12}-438409595841983065299380261100 x^{11}+2873364603192255744268399816300 x^{10}-15391336265631458455674072223920 x^9+66663169677225062255000524037200 x^8-230012314720755036612958134369600 x^7+619268712039956935144120658932800 x^6-1263340003788588238905326578718976 x^5+1869964560876940761407758850995200 x^4-1874467230564580371406607777280000 x^3+1123137350768689633740585922560000 x^2-298307678156803870881095024640000 x}{15511210043330985984000000}$

The question is, how can I find a pattern that relates the coefficients of the polynomials for each value of $n$, or an expression to span them?

It is clear that the degree corresponds to the square of $n$, and the common divisor with its factorial, in addition to the alternating signs. But the coefficients don't seem to follow a closed pattern.

Comment: Isn't this just your previous question rephrased?