# Construct next polynomial from predecessor and resulting GCD

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis

I have a sequence of polynomials built from an interpolation derived in a combinatorial problem. For each integer value of a parameter $n$ there is a different polynomial.

After trying to find a way to generate its coefficients as $n$ grows, without success, I have tried to perform the GCD of a given polynomial $P_{i}$ with the following polynomials in the sequence $P_{j}:j>i$, resulting in the same polynomial for all the following ones in the sequence. Since these resulting GCD polynomials follow a known and easier pattern, specifically the coefficients corresponding to the first-order Stirling number, I was wondering if there is any way to find the next polynomial of the original sequence from its predecessor and its GCD.

For example, the polynomial for $n=2$ is $-166 x + 243 x^2 - 86 x^3 + 9 x^4$, and for $n=3$ is $9953424 x - 31279644 x^2 + 40248308 x^3 - 27496665 x^4 + 
 10651494 x^5 - 2350026 x^6 + 291552 x^7 - 18945 x^8 + 502 x^9$

When performing its GCD it outputs $GCD(P_{2}, P_{3})=-x + x^2$, whose coefficients match the second row of the first-order Stirling number. This procedure can be executed for further $n$ values, but the polynomials are much larger.

The question is, according to the previous example, if I have the polynomial $P_{2}$ and its GCD $-x + x^2$, is there any way to construct the $P_{3}$ polynomial with that information? Also, if such a procedure exists, is it valid for further values of $n$ so that I can build all the polynomials for the next $n$ values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not.

Indeed, $GCD(P_2,P_3)=GCD(P_2,P_3+P_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there another alternative to build $P_{3}$ with $P_{2}$, or another polynomials in the sequence?

Comment: @Cardstdani : This should depend on the way the polynomials were obtained.

Comment: They come from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462225/generalization-of-polynomial-coefficients) question. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Cardstdani : I saw that, but I don't have a good idea about it.

Comment: More generally, $\gcd(P_2,P_3)=\gcd(P_2,P_3+P_2Q)$, where $Q$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @gerry-myerson Would it be possible to construct $P_{3}$ with $P_{2}$ and $GCD(P_{1},P_{2}),GCD(P_{2},P_{3})$ and more constraints about $P_{3}$ degree?

Comment: I don't see what $P_1$ has to do with it. Constraints on the degree of $P_3$ will, of course, pin it down somewhat, but not much. So long as $P_3$ has degree no smaller than that of $P_2$, there will still be many $Q$ such that $P_3+P_2Q$ has the same degree as $P_3$.